# How to use set interval to do something more than output a line? node.js

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I'm new to coding and am working on something in node.js (on Windows 10). I want to use set interval to make my code execute multiple times (not sure if I'm using the right language there), but all the examples online are like this:

```
function intervalFunc() {
  console.log('Cant stop me now!');
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 30000);
```

All that does is output the line Can't Stop Me Now every five minutes. I'd like it to actually show the weather again. Is that possible?

Here is the whole short code (I took out my actual key for obvious reasons - it is there in my own code):

```
const request = require('request');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;


let apiKey = 'my key';
let city = argv.c || 'london';
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=${city}&main.humidity=%&clouds.all=%&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`

request(url, function (err, response, body) {
  if(err){
    console.log('error:', error);
  } else {
let weather = JSON.parse(body)
    let message = `It's ${weather.clouds.all} percent cloudy, 
${weather.main.humidity} percent humid, and ${weather.main.temp} degrees in 
${weather.name}!`;


    console.log(message);
  }

function intervalFunc() {
  console.log('C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\node-weather>node index.js');
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 30000);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put request code inside interval function, something like following

```
const request = require('request');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;


let apiKey = 'my key';
let city = argv.c || 'london';
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
            q=${city}&main.humidity=%&clouds.all=%&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`

function intervalFunc() {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', error);
        } else {
            let weather = JSON.parse(body)
            let message = `It's ${weather.clouds.all} percent cloudy, 
                            ${weather.main.humidity} percent humid, and ${weather.main.temp} degrees in 
                            ${weather.name}!`;


            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 30000);
```